# Proving an invariant in a recursion using mathematical induction

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques

Given the following pseudocode for function `AP(x, y: integer)` which returns an integer,

```
function AP(x,y: integer):
    if x = 0 then return y+1
    else 
         if y = 0 then return AP(x-1,1)
         else return AP(x-1, AP(x,y-1))
```

I need to prove, $\forall x (AP(x, y) > y)$.

---

I have tried solving it using mathematical induction,
**Basis:** $AP(0, y) = y + 1$
**Inductive step:** Assuming, $AP(n, y) > y$ and $y > 0$
Prove that $AP(n + 1, y) = AP(n, AP(n + 1, y - 1)) > y$

By unrolling recursion, I get relations like,
$AP(n + 1, y) > AP(n + 1, y - 1) > AP(n, 1)$,
but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Use double induction. That is do an induction proof inside of your induction step. Or do the whole thing by strong induction on lexicographic ordering of pairs of integers.